# How to resolve tick problems in Geopandas overlay?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, geopandas

I am trying to overlay a polygon and lines in Geopandas, but I am getting tick plot problems.

`ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer`

```
import geopandas as gpd
from geopandas.tools import overlay

zip1 = "zip://data/mmcovidshp.zip"
mmcovid = gpd.read_file(zip1)
zip2 = "zip://data/roads_MM.zip"
mmroads = gpd.read_file(zip2)

overlay_intersection = overlay(mmcovid, mmroads,
                                 how='intersection')
overlay_intersection.plot(figsize=(6, 8))
```

Data: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Xxo1Ep6Dgau5ThmNetuqzehpSh9sgpfP?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear what are you trying to do.

`overlay_intersection` is empty because it tries to preserve the geometry type of the left GeoDataFrame. Because the left gdf are polygons and intersection of polygon and linestring is linestring, the result is empty. You can control that using `keep_geom_type` keyword. `keep_geom_type=False` returns everything.

The simple solution here is to change order.

```py
overlay_intersection = overlay(mmroads, mmcovid
                                 how='intersection')
```

That produces non-empty gdf. See more https://geopandas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/user_guide/set_operations.html?highlight=overlay.

If you are trying to simply clip `mmroads` to `mmcovid`'s shape, use `geopandas.clip`.  https://geopandas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gallery/plot_clip.html